# Calling script with start/stop

Tags: server

I wonder if system will call my script located in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` or `/etc/network/if-down.d/` with start or stop. The reason I am asking is that I have a script which can be called with start/stop command line arguments. In order to use with `if-up.d` I have to split the script into 2 parts. Is there a better way to place the script into `/etc/network/if-up.d/` without splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the real script in one directory, and a symlink to it in the other. Then you could check $0 each time the script gets called, to see which version was invoked. This way you would retain the conveniance to edit the script in one place.

$0 is the variable, which contains the entire path to the script itself when it gets called. You would find a "if-up" or "if-down" as part of the path, and this could be interpreted as start and stop.